# When using seek(0,0), it arbitrarily deletes the lines at the top of file in python

Tags: python, file, seek

```
import datetime         #To use date time functionality

file_log = open('.\Log_Detailed.log', 'w')
file_log.write("1 \n");file_log.write("2 \n");file_log.write("3 \n");file_log.write("4 \n");file_log.write("5 \n");file_log.write("6 \n");file_log.write("7 \n");file_log.write("8 \n");file_log.write("9 \n");file_log.write("10 \n");
file_log.write("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
file_log.write("                             LTE RRC PARSER                                 \n")
file_log.write("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
file_log.write("\n\n")
file_log.write("Cases Execution Started At : " + datetime.datetime.now().ctime())
file_log.write("\n\n")

file_log.seek(0);             #This line is the problem
file_log.write("\n***********************SUMMARY*************************\n")
file_log.write("No. of cases Passed =\n");
file_log.write("No. of cases Failed =\n");
file_log.write("*********************************************************\n");
file_log.close();
```

When I run the above code commenting out the "file_log.seek(0,0)", it prints the following output:

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         LTE RRC PARSER                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cases Execution Started At : Thu Aug  7 12:26:32 2014

But when I run the above code the output appears as follows:-

```
***********************SUMMARY*************************
```

No. of cases Passed =

No. of cases Failed =

```
*********************************************************

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cases Execution Started At : Thu Aug  7 12:35:28 2014

As you can see in the second output many of the lines has been overwritten ambiguously! After using seek(0,0), it overwrites more lines than needed. What I want is SUMMARY portion written before LTE RRC. Plz Help!

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You seek'd back to the top of the file and overwrote the lines there. Seek does not let you insert lines into a file, just overwrite them. Why not leave a blank space at the top of the file that is the size of the summary message?

Comment: Why don't you just write the lines in the order you want? Why `seek` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see in the second output many of the lines has been overwritten ambiguously!

No, it is not ambiguously.

It overwrites exactly as many bytes(!) as needed.

```
file_log.write("\n***********************SUMMARY*************************\n")
file_log.write("No. of cases Passed =\n");
file_log.write("No. of cases Failed =\n");
file_log.write("*********************************************************\n");
```

writes exactly 159 bytes to the file (unless you use Windows and a text file, in these cases `\n` is replaced with `\r\n` and you end up having 164 bytes).

So the first 159 (or 164) bytes of the file is overwritten. As the lines you had in the file are quite short, you lose more lines as if they were longer.

Comment: @user2168281 You can thank me by accepting this answer (if you think it was better than the other) and/or by upvoting it (once you have at least 15 reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Files aren't *lines*. They are characters or bytes

When you seek back to the beginning, you are overwriting that many characters.
If you need to do it this way round, you'll have to calculate the number of bytes in advance so you can leave enough space.

Perhaps you can write the file like this leaving empty spaces (after the =) to be overwritten later.

```
file_log.write("\n***********************SUMMARY*************************\n")
file_log.write("No. of cases Passed =        \n");
file_log.write("No. of cases Failed =        \n");
file_log.write("*********************************************************\n");
file_log.write("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
file_log.write("                             LTE RRC PARSER                                 \n")
file_log.write("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
file_log.write("\n\n")
file_log.write("Cases Execution Started At : " + datetime.datetime.now().ctime())
file_log.write("\n\n")
```